# Rotating an bitmap under animation

Tags: android, animation

I created an animation along the path from the following code.

```
    public void doAnimation(){
        Matrix mxTransform=new Matrix();
        PathMeasure pm=new PathMeasure(path,false);
        float fSegmentLen = (float)((pm.getLength())/50);
        if(iCurStep<=50){
            pm.getMatrix(fSegmentLen * iCurStep, mxTransform,
                    PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG + PathMeasure.TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG );
             canvas.drawBitmap(bt, mxTransform, null);
             iCurStep++;
             invalidate();
        }
        else{               
            iCurStep=0;
            animate=0;
            canvas.drawPoint((float)range-10,0f,forPoint);
        }
    }
```

Now i wanted the bitmap in the code to be rotated while drawing it using the drawBitmap() methos. Thank sin advance.

Answer (score 1):

For rotate the image, you can use the following code

```
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap src, float degree) {
    // create new matrix
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // setup rotation degree
    matrix.postRotate(degree);

    // return new bitmap rotated using matrix
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

if you want more explanation means refer this link http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-rotate-image-on-the-fly/